# Recursively check parenthesis balance of an equation in C

Tags: c, recursion, stack

I am trying to write a program in C that recursively checks the balance of an equations parenthesis. I.e. for every open there is a closing.

This is what I currently have, but I can't get it to ignore characters and spaces.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_SIZE 100

struct Stack{
    int top;
    char arr[MAX_SIZE];
} st;

void init(){
    st.top = -1;
}

bool isEmpty(){
    if(st.top == -1){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

bool isFull(){
    if(st.top == MAX_SIZE-1){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

void push(char item){
    if(isFull()){
            printf("Stack is full");
            exit(0);
    }else{
        st.top++;
        st.arr[st.top] = item;
    }
}

void pop(){
    if(isEmpty()){
        printf("Stack is empty");
        exit(0);
    }else{
        st.top--;
    }
}

char gettop(){
    return st.arr[st.top];
}

bool ArePair(char opening,char closing)
{
        if(opening == '(' && closing == ')') return true;
        else if(opening == '{' && closing == '}') return true;
        else if(opening == '[' && closing == ']') return true;
        return false;
}

void main()
{
    char in_expr[MAX_SIZE],a,temp;
    int length=0,i,j,count;

    init();
    printf("Enter an expression to check:");
    scanf("%s", in_expr);
    length = strlen(in_expr);

    for(i=0;i<length;i++){
         if (in_expr[i] !=  '(' && in_expr[i] != ')' && in_expr[i] != '{' && in_expr[i] != '}' && in_expr[i] != '[' && in_expr[i] !=  ']') {
                i++;
        }
        else if(in_expr[i] == '(' || in_expr[i] == '{' || in_expr[i] == '['){
                push(in_expr[i]);
                a = in_expr[i];
                printf("%c",a);
        }
        else if(in_expr[i] == ')' || in_expr[i] == '}' || in_expr[i] == ']'){
//                       a = st.arr[st.top];
                a = in_expr[i];
                printf("%c", a);
        }
        if(isEmpty() || !ArePair(gettop(),in_expr[i])){
          printf("\nInvalid expression - Not Balanced!\n");
                exit(0);
        }
        else{
                pop();
            }
        i++;
//        }
    }
    if(isEmpty()){
        printf("\nValid expression - Perfectly Balanced!\n");
    }else{
        printf("\nInvalid expression - Not Balanced!\n");
    }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated and if you need more details, don't hesitate to ask! If this is a duplicate I apologize, I am still searching for another solution through other posts here.

Comment: There isn't any recursion in your example. Why not just `continue;` in your first case where you've decided the character isn't one you're interested in? You don't need any of the additional `i++` other than the one in the actual for loop either.

Comment: What I would do is get rid of the first if completely, make the else if after it an if, then move the `if(isEmpty()...` inside the closing case since you don't want to check it when you've just found an opening or a character you don't care about.

Comment: If the code already work then [codereview.se] may be a better site to post this (not in this case) (but remember to read their help center before asking, as always).

Comment: There are multiple questions about checking balanced parentheses or balanced brackets — and most of them use a stack rather than recursion, just like your code is attempting to do.

Answer (score 2):

A few bugs:

Don't do `i++` except in the `for` clause. You're [potentially] skipping past chars that you want to see.

Also, don't check for `isEmpty` or `ArePair` *unless* the current char is a closer.

---

Here's a corrected version [please pardon the gratuitous style cleanup]. Note that there may be other bugs, but I think this will get you closer:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_SIZE 100

struct Stack {
    int top;
    char arr[MAX_SIZE];
} st;

void
init()
{
    st.top = -1;
}

bool
isEmpty()
{
    if (st.top == -1) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

bool
isFull()
{
    if (st.top == MAX_SIZE - 1) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

void
push(char item)
{
    if (isFull()) {
        printf("Stack is full");
        exit(0);
    }
    else {
        st.top++;
        st.arr[st.top] = item;
    }
}

void
pop()
{
    if (isEmpty()) {
        printf("Stack is empty");
        exit(0);
    }
    else {
        st.top--;
    }
}

char
gettop()
{
    return st.arr[st.top];
}

bool
ArePair(char opening, char closing)
{
    if (opening == '(' && closing == ')')
        return true;
    else if (opening == '{' && closing == '}')
        return true;
    else if (opening == '[' && closing == ']')
        return true;
    return false;
}

void
main()
{
    char in_expr[MAX_SIZE],
     a,
     temp;
    int length = 0,
        i,
        j,
        count;

    init();
#if 0
    printf("Enter an expression to check:");
    scanf("%s", in_expr);
#else
    strcpy(in_expr,"( ( a + b ) * (c + d) ) * ( ( w + x ) * (y + z) )");
    //strcpy(in_expr,"( ( a + b ) * (c + d) ) * ( ( w + x ) * y + z) )");
#endif
    length = strlen(in_expr);

    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        int chr = in_expr[i];
        printf("input: '%c'\n",chr);

        if (chr != '(' && chr != ')' && chr != '{' && chr != '}' && chr != '[' && chr != ']') {
            //i++;
            continue;
        }

        if (chr == '(' || chr == '{' || chr == '[') {
            push(chr);
            a = chr;
            printf("%c", a);
            continue;
        }

        if (chr == ')' || chr == '}' || chr == ']') {
            a = chr;
            printf("%c", a);
        }

        if (isEmpty() || !ArePair(gettop(), chr)) {
            printf("\nInvalid expression - Not Balanced!\n");
            exit(0);
        }
        else {
            pop();
        }
        //i++;
    }
    if (isEmpty()) {
        printf("\nValid expression - Perfectly Balanced!\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("\nInvalid expression - Not Balanced!\n");
    }
}
```

---

Here's a version that uses a `switch` statement that may be easier to read:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_SIZE 100

struct Stack {
    int top;
    char arr[MAX_SIZE];
} st;

void
init()
{
    st.top = -1;
}

bool
isEmpty()
{
    if (st.top == -1) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

bool
isFull()
{
    if (st.top == MAX_SIZE - 1) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

void
push(char item)
{
    if (isFull()) {
        printf("Stack is full");
        exit(0);
    }
    else {
        st.top++;
        st.arr[st.top] = item;
    }
}

void
pop()
{
    if (isEmpty()) {
        printf("Stack is empty");
        exit(0);
    }
    else {
        st.top--;
    }
}

char
gettop()
{
    return st.arr[st.top];
}

bool
ArePair(char opening, char closing)
{
    if (opening == '(' && closing == ')')
        return true;
    else if (opening == '{' && closing == '}')
        return true;
    else if (opening == '[' && closing == ']')
        return true;
    return false;
}

void
main()
{
    char in_expr[MAX_SIZE],
     a,
     temp;
    int length = 0,
        i,
        j,
        count;

    init();
#if 0
    printf("Enter an expression to check:");
    scanf("%s", in_expr);
#else
    strcpy(in_expr,"( ( a + b ) * (c + d) ) * ( ( w + x ) * (y + z) )");
    //strcpy(in_expr,"( ( a + b ) * (c + d) ) * ( ( w + x ) * y + z) )");
#endif
    length = strlen(in_expr);

    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        int chr = in_expr[i];
        printf("input: '%c'\n",chr);

        switch (chr) {
        case '(':
        case '{':
        case '[':
            push(chr);
            a = chr;
            printf("%c", a);
            break;
        }

        case ')':
        case '}':
        case ']':
            a = chr;
            printf("%c", a);
            if (isEmpty() || !ArePair(gettop(), chr)) {
                printf("\nInvalid expression - Not Balanced!\n");
                exit(0);
            }

            pop();
            break;
        }
    }

    if (isEmpty()) {
        printf("\nValid expression - Perfectly Balanced!\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("\nInvalid expression - Not Balanced!\n");
    }
}
```

---

Here's a version that adds a self test function that allows multiple unit tests. It's what I've done when I've written expression parsers in the past.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_SIZE 100

struct Stack {
    int top;
    char arr[MAX_SIZE];
} st;

void
init()
{
    st.top = -1;
}

bool
isEmpty()
{
    if (st.top == -1) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

bool
isFull()
{
    if (st.top == MAX_SIZE - 1) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

void
push(char item)
{
    if (isFull()) {
        printf("Stack is full");
        exit(0);
    }
    else {
        st.top++;
        st.arr[st.top] = item;
    }
}

void
pop()
{
    if (isEmpty()) {
        printf("Stack is empty");
        exit(0);
    }
    else {
        st.top--;
    }
}

char
gettop()
{
    return st.arr[st.top];
}

bool
ArePair(char opening, char closing)
{
    if (opening == '(' && closing == ')')
        return true;
    else if (opening == '{' && closing == '}')
        return true;
    else if (opening == '[' && closing == ']')
        return true;
    return false;
}

// RETURNS: 1=balanced, 0=unbalanced
int
test_expr(const char *in_expr)
{
    int i;
    int length;

    //printf("\ntest_expr: '%s'\n",in_expr);

    init();
    length = strlen(in_expr);

    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        int chr = in_expr[i];
        //printf("input: '%c'\n",chr);

        switch (chr) {
        case '(':
        case '{':
        case '[':
            push(chr);
            //printf("%c", chr);
            break;

        case ')':
        case '}':
        case ']':
            //printf("%c", chr);
            if (isEmpty() || !ArePair(gettop(), chr)) {
                printf("Invalid expression - Not Balanced!\n");
                return 0;
                exit(0);
            }

            pop();
            break;
        }
    }

    if (isEmpty()) {
        printf("Valid expression - Perfectly Balanced!\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        printf("Invalid expression - Not Balanced!\n");
        return 0;
    }
}

void
testone(int expected,const char *expr)
{
    int isvalid;

    printf("\ntestone: '%s'\n",expr);
    isvalid = test_expr(expr);
    printf("%s\n", (isvalid == expected) ? "PASS" : "FAIL");
}

void
testall(void)
{

    testone(1,"( ( a + b ) * (c + d) ) * ( ( w + x ) * (y + z) )");
    testone(0," ( a + b ) * (c + d) ) * ( ( w + x ) * (y + z) )");
    testone(0,"( ( a + b ) * (c + d) ) * ( ( w + x ) * y + z) )");
    testone(0,"( ( a + b ) * (c + d) ) * ( ( w + x ) * (y + z) ");
    testone(0,"( ( a + b ) * (c + d) ) * ( ( w + x ) * (y + z )");
    testone(0,"( ( a + b ) * (c + d) ] * ( ( w + x ) * (y + z) )");
}

int
main(void)
{

#if 0
    char in_expr[MAX_SIZE];
    printf("Enter an expression to check:");
    scanf("%s", in_expr);
    test_expr(in_expr);
#else
    testall();
#endif

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is a vast improvement! Thank you immensly. For clarification, what are the "#if #else #endif" statements?

Comment: The `#if 0/#else/#endif` [or `#if 1/#else/#endif`] blocks are a "trick" to allow alternate code to be tried, without having to delete the original code. A simple `#if 0 some_code #endif` is like commenting out "some_code", but it's faster for multiline blocks (and better than trying a `/* some_code */` pairing [particularly if the code has K&R comments]. You can also do `#ifdef USE_OLD_CODE` as the alternate. When the code is fully working, you can remove them. Notice in my third example how you can revert to your original code (prompt user for expression) easily

Answer (score 0):

You can take a simpler approach with an incremental state that stores the pending blocks, for example a `char` array with the opening characters.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_EXPR  256
#define MAX_LEVEL  32

enum { EXPR_BALANCED, EXPR_TOO_DEEP, EXPR_PAREN_MISMATCH, EXPR_UNCLOSED_PAREN };

int check_balance(const char *expr) {
    char state[MAX_LEVEL];
    const char *p;
    int level = 0;
    state[level++] = 0;  // force mismatch on state[0]
    for (p = expr; *p; p++) {
        switch (*p) {
          case '(':
          case '{':
          case '[':
            if (level >= MAX_LEVEL)
                return EXPR_TOO_DEEP;
            state[level++] = *p;
            break;
          case ')':
            if (state[--level] != '(')
                return EXPR_PAREN_MISMATCH;
            break;
          case '}':
            if (state[--level] != '{')
                return EXPR_PAREN_MISMATCH;
            break;
          case ']':
            if (state[--level] != '[')
                return EXPR_PAREN_MISMATCH;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (level != 1)
        return EXPR_UNCLOSED_PAREN;

    return EXPR_BALANCED;
}

int main() {
    char expr[MAX_EXPR];

    printf("Enter expressions to check, one per line: ");
    while (fgets(expr, sizeof expr, stdin) {
         switch (check_balance(expr)) {
           case EXPR_TOO_DEEP:
             printf("too many nesting levels\n");
             break;
           case EXPR_PAREN_MISMATCH:
             printf("closing character mismatch\n");
             break;
           case EXPR_UNCLOSED_PAREN:
             printf("closing character missing\n");
             break;
           case EXPR_BALANCED:
             printf("expression is balanced\n");
             break;
         }
    }
    return 0;
}
```